# Given a Pandas DataFrame With a MultiIndex of Size 2, How Can I Access Data Using Only the Second Set of Index Values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've been trying to figure out how to use MultiIndexes in Pandas. Here's the details. Given the following dataset:

```
user movie  rating
196  242    3
186  302    3
22   377    1
244  51     2
166  346    1
```

Where "user" and "movie" are used as Indexers and "rating" is a column, it's simple to access a "user" by the following:

```py
df.loc[196]
```

However, I also need to be able to access data for a given "movie" without considering the "user" Indexer. The following attempts do not work:

```py
df.loc[,302] # Syntax Error
df.loc[:,302] # Key Error
df[:][302] # Index Error
df.loc[:].loc[302] # Only accesses "user" Indexer
```

Surely, Pandas must provide a simple way to access individual Indexers beyond just the first, but I haven't figured it out. In my mind, the Pandas implementation for accessing data with MultiIndexers should be similar to accessing Numpy arrays. If not, I will just have to use Numpy rather than Pandas.

Comment: `df.loc[(slice(None), 302), :]`

Comment: Awesome. The syntax is a bit weird, but that did the trick. Thanks for the help. Would you like to add the answer? If not, I could do it and mention you as the source.

Comment: Question has been closed as a dupe, so no answers possible. That syntax is in one of the answers to the dupe.

Comment: Thanks @Nick. Perhaps the different phrasing in my question will help someone find the answer in the future. I saw a solution similar to yours in another post, but the scenario being asked was a bit different, and because the syntax is a little awkward in my opinion, I couldn't tell if that was what I needed or not. I suppose it helps to have multiple queries to the same answer. Your example is more concise than those in that linked answer though.

Comment: Hopefully so. I agree on the syntax, you'd expect to be able to use `:` as you can for the columns, given you can use `slice(None)` there e.g. `df.loc[(slice(None), 302), slice(None)]`